# How to access local plaintext js file and save as variable

Tags: javascript, json, object

I realize this may be a trivial question, but I'm hitting a wall trying to access some simple JSON data.

Basically, I have a .js file that contains an object containing all the data I need to access.

However, the data isn't assigned to a JS variable in the .js file itself- it's just *there*.

Here's an example of all that is in the file:

---

```
{"data":[
    {"example" : "1",
    "example2" : "2",
    "example3" : {
        "test" : "JS"
    }}
    ]
}
```

---

How can I access this data, assign it a variable, and manipulate it in a separate HTML/JS file?

Comment: That isn't valid JS. (It could be JSON though).

Comment: What JavaScript runtime are you using? Node.js? Windows Scripting Host? An HTML document loaded into a web browser?

Comment: What does "local" mean? A file on the user's file system? The same web server as the HTML document hosting the program?

Comment: Thanks, Quentin. I'm just loading this into an HTML doc in Chrome. And yes- the file is on the user's file system.

Comment: Please avoid putting pictures of text in to questions. It makes it impossible to copy/paste into a test case.

Comment: Oh, and I retract my statement about it being JSON. It's simply invalid. Array literals don't have `name: value` pairs in them.

Comment: sounds like you need to use `FileReader()` to fetch the local file contents, then `JSON.parse()` the result. (if it's valid)

Comment: Whoops! Right you are... forgot to add those outer curly braces for that object within the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access arbitrary files on the user's file system. You have to provide a file input and have the user select it.

Then you can use the [the file api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) to read it.

`JSON.parse` will convert it to a JavaScript data structure.

```js
document.querySelector("[type=file]").addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  var file = this.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    console.log(JSON.parse(this.result));
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
});
```

```html
<input type="file">
```